# Using sum function with a condition based on a returned value

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a set of given month with a number of hours related to each of it

```
DATE          HOURS
8/1/2013      3
9/1/2013      8
10/1/2013     2
11/1/2013     4
12/1/2013     1
```

I need to return the sum of hours for everything that is in the past including current month, in the example below, starting in august, sum would be august only. For september, I'd need august + september

```
DATE          HOURS     SUM
8/1/2013      3         3
9/1/2013      8         11
10/1/2013     2         13
11/1/2013     4         17
12/1/2013     1         18
```

I am not sure how to proceed, since the date condition is different for each line.

If anyone can help on this, it'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  You could also search for 'sql running total' to find a number of examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in most SQL dialects using a correlated subquery (or a non-equijoin, but I find the subquery cleaner):

```
select date, hours,
       (select sum(t2.hours)
        from t t2
        where t2.date <= t.date
       ) as cum
from t;
```

Many SQL engines also support the cumulative sum function, which would typically look like this:

```
select date, hours sum(hours) over (order by date) as cum
from t
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it's exactly what I was looking for